# iOS Drag a CCSprite not working?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

So I'm using cocos2d and trying to drag a sprite across the screen, it was working prior to this.. but I can't seem to figure out what I did to make it not work. I'm seeing the ccTouchBegan and ccTouchEnd methods being called but not the ccTouchMoved.

I tried converting over to ccTouchesBegan, ccTouchesMoved, and ccTouchesEnded but am still only seeing the Began and Ended methods being called. Obviously I've commented out or changed a setting somewhere. I also commented out [[CCTouchDispatch sharedDisptacher] ...]; because it error'd with the ccTouches methods because it's native touches I believe.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Search Google for Cocos2d sample projects with touch events. They offer you the right guidance.

Comment: I don't see much of anything with that search. I know how to use touch events in cocos2d, I'm trying to figure out why my ccTouchMoved event isn't triggering while my ccTouchBegan and ccTouchEnded methods are triggering.. If you've found something that shows me this please share. I can't seem to find what you have found.

Comment: Well. From my experience `touchesMoved` should get called. Try NSLogging the coordinates .

Answer (score 0):

Did you add yourself as a delegate?

```
[[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher]addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:NO];
```

And then try this:

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    mySprite.position = location;
}
```

Comment: Yes, was still getting the same result- tried swallowsTouches:YES and NO as well.

I've decided to change and just use the UIPanGestureRecognizer.. still not sure what the issue is, but I have what I need working now!

Comment: Do you have other layers on top of your current one? We had this problem back then and was solved by centralizing all touch events to a single class.

Comment: Hmm maybe I'll attempt that and just send out notifications to each appropriate class. There's something weird going on, probably layering  somewhere.. It's my first iPhone app so the code's a bit messy. I'm going to attempt to figure this out a bit later though- since I have what I need set up now, I want to continue with development. Thanks for your suggestions and help :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do the moving of the sprite using the ccTouchMoved Easily.

Please try the below code. I made a short demo for my understanding of the same concept of yours. It works for me.

```
- (void)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    for (int i = 0; i < touches.count; i++) {

        UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
        CGPoint location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector]
                            convertToGL:touchLocation];
        if(CGRectContainsPoint([sprite boundingBox], location))
             sprite.position = ccp(location.x,location.y);
    }
}
```